# Why does createCDATAsection add whitespace to start end end of the line?

Tags: php, domdocument, cdata

Here is my source code:

```
dom = new \DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$translationXml = $dom->createElement('translation');
$translationXml->setAttribute('lang', $language->url_key);
$translationXml->setAttribute('website', $websiteId);
$translationXml->appendChild($dom->createCDATASection('<test>'));
$dom->appendChild($translationXml);
$dom->formatOutput = true;
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

And folowing is output:

```
<translation lang="en" website="4">
    <![CDATA[ <test> ]]>
</translation>
```

How to remove that spaces?

Comment: Cant reproduce the space, https://3v4l.org/Cvrds

Comment: @LawrenceCherone , strange sh*t

Comment: I've just tested it in a browser instead, sure thing it shows the spacing, view the source and your see it has no spacing.. dont trust everything you see ;p